# Is it possible to format legend text based on a field?

Tags: qgis, legend, text, format

I have a map of companies in Europe, they are symbolised with lettered points so that I don't have to wrestle with many labels, and then the points are to be defined in the legend. What I would like to do is format the legend text (i.e. have some italic, or strikethrough etc.), dependent on whether or not the company is a member of a conglomorate which I have stored in a field as "Current".

When in the layout view I'm looking at the properties for the legend. I can see next to the strikethrough font there is the option to use an attribute field however when I hover over it there is no option to select a field.

[image]

Is there another way to go about what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a field to dictate this, open the same menu and click Edit.

This will open an expression dialog where you can determine what field to use and how.

You will probably need to use a CASE WHEN code.

Comment: When I try that, it just comes up with NULL rather than a list of fields.

Comment: That would be because, the presumption is, there will be more than one layer in a legend, but you want a uniform look for the legend (usually).

Comment: Hmmm, I only have one layer in the legend. Maybe I'll just have to manually edit each one.

Comment: This is the most work/least searching option. Check this if it helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384319/populate-legend-items-with-values-from-another-layer